# Why is Module not found from Moralis in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ethereum, web3js, moralis

I am currently in the process of developing a dApp for a local business, however the moralis node module seems to have started to get buggy.

I am using Next.js & React with Yarn

i ran yarn add moralis with the error as
[image]

as a result the local server throws this error​
[image]

I have tried uninstalling package and reinstalling, removing yarn.lock and package-lock.

I have tried all the other locations available for the (import Moralis from "Location") spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize Moralis at the root level of your React application (e.g., in your index.js or App.js file). This will ensure that Moralis is initialized only once when your app starts:

```
// index.js or App.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'; // Your main application component
import Moralis from 'moralis';

Moralis.start({ apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY' });

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

it should look like this if you are using react moralis
`const { Moralis } = useMoralis()`. Right now you are importing it from the wrong path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).